# Multi output regression analysis learning curve

Tags: neural-network, regression

I am quite new in data science. I have been following Andrew Ng's machine learning course. 
I am employing neural networks for a 2-input 2-output regression problem for a robotics project
The architecture of the network has only 1 hidden layer with 10 neurons. The training size is 2160 and the cross validation set size is 720.
I have plotted the learning curves for 100 samples and this is what I get . (Please refer figure). I am not sure what to make of it, whether it is overfitting or underfitting, since the errors are low even from the beginning itself. How can I improve the performance?[image]

Comment: What kind of error is that?

Comment: It is the mean squared error